# Unable to build CSS with tailwind

Tags: npm, tailwind-css

No matter how many times I try to install the `autoprefixer`, this error is thrown

```
>npx tailwindcss@latest build ./src/styles.css -o ./dist/styles.css
npx: installed 80 in 5.546s
Cannot find module 'autoprefixer'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\Q\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_npx\62760\node_modules\tailwindcss\lib\cli\commands\build.js
- C:\Users\Q\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_npx\62760\node_modules\tailwindcss\lib\cli\commands\index.js
- C:\Users\Q\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_npx\62760\node_modules\tailwindcss\lib\cli\main.js
- C:\Users\Q\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_npx\62760\node_modules\tailwindcss\lib\cli.js
```

```
>npm install autoprefixer
npm WARN @tailwindcss/custom-forms@0.2.1 requires a peer of tailwindcss@^1.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @tailwindcss/typography@0.2.0 requires a peer of tailwindcss@^1.5.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @tailwindcss/ui@0.6.2 requires a peer of tailwindcss@^1.8.3 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
```

What could be missing?

Comment: What happen when you are trying to install autoprefixer?

Comment: Try enire thing `npm install -D tailwindcss@latest postcss@latest autoprefixer@latest`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now, I'm able to reproduce this error. I assume that you install the `tailwindcss` using following command (as mentioned on [home page](https://tailwindcss.com/))

```
$ npm install tailwindcss
```

But, this alone does not work. Because, `tailwindcss` is a PostCSS plugin and you need it in order to compile `tailwindcss`. Apart from this, you also need `autoprefixer` plugin as `tailwindcss` use it.

You can install these plugins using following command.

```
$ npm i -D autoprefixer postcss
```

Then create a `config` file using following command.

```
$ npx tailwindcss init
```

Finally, then run your to build.

```
$ npx tailwindcss@latest build ./src/styles.css -o ./dist/styles.css
```

Also, if the project on which you're currently working is still in initial state then I would suggest you to configure the project again as mentioned in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qYgogv4R8zg&ab_channel=TailwindLabs).